# Handle ActionScript runtime errors

Tags: actionscript-3

Good day!

What is the best\recommended way of handling runtime errors in AS3? I mean errors that were not catched by `try...catch`. I'd like to log such errors and provide some handler to show user some message? May be there are some AS3-specific best practicies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flash Player 10.1 and a [global error handler](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2009/10/global_error_handling_in_air_20.html).

Comment: Nope. That's why https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-444 existed for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is providing a patch :D

But until then, your suggestion is probably the best way to go. Present the user with a notification and send a report to your server, or something like that. Depending on the severity of the error, you might want to advice the user to reload.

greetz
back2dos

Comment: The main question is: how to handle this 'unhandled' errors? :) The AS3 is event-based in it's nature.

Comment: @artvolk: It seemed like you were asking about best practices, not about implementation details. As for implementation, splash provided the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, may be I was unclear -- the problem is how to catch this errors, not how to show them to the user or log...

Please see link to bugreport above in splash's post